# How to watch a h263 video via rtsp with gstreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, rtsp-client, h.263

I'm trying to read a video stream, encoded in the h263 format, that I'm receiving via rtsp, with gstreamer, on windows. At the end, I have to get a BGR or RGB format (to use Qimage/Qt).

I can watch the flow with **vlc** `rtsp://172.22.1.2:8554/test`

I can watch the flow with a **cmd** :
    `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://172.22.1.2:8554/test ! rtph263pdepay ! avdec_h263 ! autovideosink`

I can't do this **in my program**.
I tried `m_pipeline = gst_parse_launch("rtspsrc location=rtsp://172.22.1.2:8554/test ! rtph263pdepay ! avdec_h263 ! appsink name=sink caps=video/x-raw, format=BGR", &error);`

I tried `uridecodebin uri=..` in state of `rtspsrc location=..`.

I tried `video/x-h263` and `video/x-raw, format=RGB`

Wether I have an error message about the caps, or the program crashes.

I don't know if I don't use the right elements or if the end of my command is wrong or something else..?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting an error because avdec_h263's src caps do not match the caps you have specified for the appsink. Running the cmd `gst-inspect-1.0 avdec_h264` you can see that the src pad caps template supports only `video/x-raw format = I420`, while your appsink is set to `video/x-raw format=BGR`.

Try adding the `videoconvert` element to your pipeline between the decoder and appsink : 
`m_pipeline = gst_parse_launch("rtspsrc location=rtsp://172.22.1.2:8554/test ! rtph263pdepay ! avdec_h263 ! videoconvert ! appsink name=sink caps=video/x-raw, format=BGR", &error);`

Comment: I already tried this without succes, but I found others errors since, so I will retry this. Unfortunately I can not try before tuesday =/

Comment: Finally I don't use gstreamer, only opencv with cv::VideoCapture("rtsp://...").
Thank you!